# get_meta_tags and persian phrases

Tags: php

I used this function,

```
 $code = get_meta_tags('http://www.narenji.ir/');
```

and I've seen this

```
  'Ù…Ú©Ø§Ù†ÛŒ Ø¨Ø±Ø§ÛŒ Ø¢Ø´Ù†Ø§ÛŒÛŒ Ø¨Ø§ Ø§Ø¨Ø²Ø§Ø±Ù‡Ø§ Ùˆ Ø§Ø®Ø¨Ø§Ø± Ø¯Ø§Øº Ø¯Ù†ÛŒØ§ÛŒ ÙÙ†Ø§ÙˆØ±ÛŒ'
```

How can I fix this issue?
Can I fix it without using JSON?

Comment: How are you echoing `$code` to your page? What encoding are you using?

Comment: I have decoded with this function 
utf8_decode();
But I did not get a useful result.

Comment: I think you can fix it with J§ØN.

Comment: I know, But I wanna know, Does PHP have any option for persian phrases?

Comment: @wandad, PHP has nothing to do with Persian phrases, but the encoding does. You should collate source and target encoding to get the result. Try setting force `header()` for UTF-8 when `echo`ing your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are executing your script from a browser, make sure you sending UTF-8 as your content encoding. Add a `Content-Type` header *before* echo'ing anything.

```
header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Answer (score 2):

You must be missing some link here, your code just works:

- [Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/1iMNak)

The key point is that you *preserve* the UTF-8 encoding so that Persian is supported. Otherwise you would need some other encoding (one that I do not yet know) that supports Persian and a library that is able to re-encode that.

Which encoding do you want to use for Persian output?

Answer (score 0):

`utf8_decode()` is built specifically for converting from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 (latin1). Persian characters are not in Latin1, so why would you feel it's necessary here??

working example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/tEjZAz